# T-Sql How to get Max dated records?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want max dated rows for per `GroupCode`
I wrote this.

```
SELECT FH.BelgeNo AS FaturaNo
    ,FHD.UrunId
    ,FH.Tarih
    ,UG.Grup AS GrupKodu
    ,FHD.Kodu
    ,FHD.UrunAdi
    ,FHD.BirimFiyat
FROM FirmaHareketDetayi FHD
LEFT JOIN FirmaHareketleri FH ON FH.ID = FHD.HareketId
LEFT JOIN Urunler U ON U.UrunId = FHD.UrunId --and U.Kodu = FHD.Kodu
LEFT JOIN UrunGruplari UG ON UG.GrupId = U.GrupId
WHERE FHD.Kodu = '2S619H307CF'
    AND FH.FirmaId = 2610
ORDER BY Tarih DESC
```

and results are like this

There are 2 `PIERBURG` rows. 
[image]

is it possible to get only one `PIERBURG` ? 
I mean max dated one  (Tarih: Date column, GrupKodu: Group Code)

Notes: Table UrunGrupları: ProductGroups
Table FirmaHareketleri: FirmMovements
Table FirmaHareketDetayi: FirmMovementDetails (Connected with FirmMovements by HareketId (Foreign Key))

Sorry about my english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions for this

```
    ;with cte as (
    SELECT FH.BelgeNo AS FaturaNo
        ,FHD.UrunId
        ,FH.Tarih
        ,UG.Grup AS GrupKodu
        ,FHD.Kodu
        ,FHD.UrunAdi
        ,FHD.BirimFiyat
        , row_number() over(partition by UG.Grup order by FH.Tarih desc) as rownum
    FROM FirmaHareketDetayi FHD
    LEFT JOIN FirmaHareketleri FH ON FH.ID = FHD.HareketId
    LEFT JOIN Urunler U ON U.UrunId = FHD.UrunId --and U.Kodu = FHD.Kodu
    LEFT JOIN UrunGruplari UG ON UG.GrupId = U.GrupId
    WHERE FHD.Kodu = '2S619H307CF'
        AND FH.FirmaId = 2610    
    )

    select *
    from cte
    where rownum = 1
```

Comment: when I removed second ORDER BY Tarih DESC part and it  works! thank you